# Is there a way to get async workflows in F# to pipeline automatically?

Tags: asynchronous, f#, workflow

(Note I'm talking about pipelining as in running independent processes in parallel; not related to the |> operator).

So if I've got two functions

```
let incr x = 
  Thread.Sleep 1000
  x + 1

let product x y = 
  Thread.Sleep 1000
  x * y
```

would there be an easy way to write a workflow something like (pseudocode)

```
let productOfIncrements x y = 
  async {
    let! x1 = incr x
    let! y1 = incr y
    let! result = product x1 y1
    return result
  }
```

that pipelines the first two independent operations and thus executes in two seconds, or are async workflows the wrong approach to this problem?  If there is a good approach to the problem, is there a straightforward way to extend such an approach to do, say, recursive factorial calculation in N+1 seconds rather than 2N?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest option is to use `Async.StartChild`. This primitve starts an asynchronous operation in background (in a thread pool) and returns a "token" that can be used to wait for a completion of the operation. This doesn't block the workflow, so you can then continue running other operations:

```
let productOfIncrements x y = 
  async {
    // Start the 'incr x' operation in background
    let! x1Op = async {return incr x} |> Async.StartChild
    // Continue doing other work 
    // (synchronously since it takes the same time as the above.)
    let y1 = incr y
    // Now wait for the result of 'incr x' (if it is still running)
    let! x1 = x1Op
    // return the product (just call the function synchronously)
    return product x1 y1
  }
```

If the two operations return the same type, then you can also use `Async.Parallel`, which composes multiple operations to run in parallel.

If you're working with purely CPU-bound computations and you need to create a large number of them, then you can also use .NET `Tasks` directly (see for example [this article](http://tomasp.net/blog/fsharp-parallel-plinq.aspx)). Tasks are more efficient, but are not as elegant to use (and don't support asynchronous waiting nicely).

As a side-note, the term *pipeline* is usually used (at least in F# or .NET world) for a more complicated thing - For example, say you have a series of steps that depend on each other. When processing multiple inputs, you can run the steps in parallel (and still limit the total paralellism). This can be done using F# async workflows too - see [for example this article](http://tomasp.net/blog/parallel-extra-image-pipeline.aspx). There is also a [framework named pipelets](https://github.com/7sharp9/pipelets) that implements the concept.

Comment: Actually what's the correct way given the definition of incr to use it in an async -- the compiler is giving me a "cannot convert int to Async<'a>".

Comment: Just wrap in an async {return ..} like this:  
    "let! y1 = async {return incr y}"?  Is it idiomatic to have asyncs within asyncs like that?

Comment: Has it been demonstrated that Tasks are more efficient than async workflows? And in which respect, are we talking something comparable to iterating over an array with a for loop vs foreach or something more significant?

Comment: @David - Asyncs are certianly not a good way to implement matrix multiplication (I tested that) - that is, spawning about 1000 CPU-bounded asyncs is less efficient than spawning 1000 CPU-bounded `Tasks`. However, in the usual use-case, asyncs work good enough and have many other benefits.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's a solution to the recursive factorial problem based on Tomas's solution to the waiting problem.  I'm still not 100% satisfied with it; I feel like the inner method should return some kind of continuation tuple or something; maintaining the running total seems somehow like "cheating", but anyway:

```
open System.Threading
open System

let decr x = 
  Thread.Sleep 1000
  x - 1

let product x y = 
  Thread.Sleep 1000
  x * y

let fact (n:int) :Async<int> = 
  let rec fact2 (x:int) (xMinus1Op:Async<int>) (runningProduct:Async<int>) :Async<int> =
      async {
        if x = 0 then 
          return! runningProduct
        else
          let! xMinus1 = xMinus1Op
          let! xMinus2Op = async {return decr xMinus1} |> Async.StartChild
          let! prod = runningProduct
          let! runningProduct = async {return product x prod} |> Async.StartChild
          // start both threads to execute simultaneously and feed them forward.
          return! fact2 xMinus1 xMinus2Op runningProduct
      }
  fact2 n (async{return decr n}) (async{return 1})

let start = Environment.TickCount
let result = fact 10 |> Async.RunSynchronously
printfn "%A" <| result
printfn "%A" <| Environment.TickCount - start //runs in 11 seconds, not 20.
```

**Edit: maybe it's more straightforward using tasks:**

```
let fact (n:int) :int = 
    let rec fact2 (x:int) (xMinus1:int) (runningProduct:int) :int =
        if x = 0 then 
            runningProduct
        else
            let xMinus2Op = new Task<int>(fun () -> decr xMinus1)
            let runningProductOp = new Task<int>(fun () -> product x runningProduct)
            xMinus2Op.Start()
            runningProductOp.Start()
            let xMinus2 = xMinus2Op.Result
            let runningProduct = runningProductOp.Result
            fact2 xMinus1 xMinus2 runningProduct
    fact2 n (decr n) (1)
```

No workflows necessary, just plain imperative code; it might even translate into C# easily.

Comment: Hmm, so the wikipedia article on "tail call" shows that a tail-callable recursive factorial function actually needs the running product; the simple "return x * fact(x-1)" isn't tail-callable because it has to do something with the return value of the inner fact call.  I think that the same thing holds true above, and so in effect the running product is necessary to avoid the decr and product calls from all happening in serial.

Comment: You can implemnt tail-call factorial by writing `let rec fact x acc = if x = 0 then acc else fact (x - 1) (acc * x)`. However, factorial is not such a great example for parallelization, because there is a data dependency - you cannot do much in parallel (calculating minus 1 on background thread is certainly slower than doing that on the main thread). You can have more fun with functions like Fibonacci (where you can actually run something in parallel)

Comment: Right, so the async factorial is similar to the tail-call factorial, except for rather than trampolining the call stack, it trampolines async processes, feeding forward both the decrement and the multiply running simultaneously.  That way you get fact(10) in 11 seconds rather than 20 seconds.